# Running a C program multiple times with different inputs each time

Tags: c

I need a way to run a c program 256 times in the terminal with the operation number being the input for the function ( i.e for 3rd time running it, input is 3) and find the value of input at which the program doesn't return a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

You can get multiple execution using a bash loop, or using seq/xargs

The code assumes that program will finish with exit code zero or crash.

```
# Bash
for ((i=1 ; i<=256 ; i++ )) do
   if ! program $i > result.$i ; then
      echo "Failed on $i"
   fi
done
```

Using seq/xargs ,one liner

```
seq 1 256 | xargs -I@ program @ '||' echo "Failed on $@" \;
```

The advantage of seq/xargs is that you can run multiple values at the same time - potential speedup.

Answer (score 0):

I think a shell script might help you

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
./program $i
exit_status=$?
if [ $exit_status -eq 127 ]; then
    echo $i
fi
done
```